# Tensorflow getting elements from a placeholder depending on another placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have some trouble coding this operation in tf. Here is an example let's assume that I have one [n,2] placeholder x and one [n,1] placeholder y.
x= [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] 
y=[1,0,1] 
for each element i from y I want to take the corresponding element from the ith 2d tensor.
In the example, the output should be [2,3,6]. I tried several techniques but without success. Is there an easy way to do that with tensorflow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use either `tf.gather_nd` or hack it manually by `tf.stack` and `tf.where`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
y = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 0, 1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    xx = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)
    ans = tf.where(tf.equal(y, tf.zeros_like(y)), xx[0], xx[1])
    print sess.run(ans)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    idx = tf.range(0, limit=3, delta=1, name='arange')
    idx = tf.stack([idx, y], axis=-1)
    ans = tf.gather_nd(x, idx)
    print sess.run(ans)
```